# Angular is not downloading due to wrong file name

Tags: angular

I am trying to download angular and keeps saying mkdirp is no longer supported and it also looks like it is going into the wrong folder... it's going into the appdata roaming.

[image]

I uninstalled node and reinstalled the newest version. I tried to update mkdirp but it will not update.

Comment: Please show logs and error messages as text, not as pictures of text. Visually impaired users, and search engines, can't read text from images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to the npm folder not being added to the environment PATH variable.

1. Open File Explorer
2. Right click on "This PC"
3. Go to "Advanced System Settings"
4. Click "Environment Variables"
5. Find the variable called "PATH" and then click "Edit"
6. Click "New"
7. In the command promp, type `%APPDATA%\npm`
8. Copy the filepath into the new line
9. Restart cmd